# Moodle Global Search issue

Tags: solr, moodle

I want Global Search in Moodle. I have configured Solr Server
But i am getting the below error message.
    Solr client error: Unsuccessful system request : Response Code 404.
    HTTP ERROR 404
    Problem accessing /solr/moodle/admin/system/. Reason: 
I am new to Moodle and dont know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that you installed php solr2 extension, see doc here :
https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Global_search#How_to_install_Solr

Also to understand Moodle errors you need to enable debug, see doc here :
https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Debugging